# microsoft graph issuing invalid token

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the access token for microsoft api to get outlook contacts into my ionic/angular webapp. First, I'm using the **implicit flow** to get the token using GET request to the authorize endpoint (v2).

I do this by sending users to following page which redirects to the url specified once signing in is complete :

```
  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?"
  +"client_id={CLIENT_ID_HERE}"
  +"&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2F"
  +"&scope=offline_access openid contacts.read"
  +" contacts.read.shared user.read"
  +"&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com"
  +"&response_mode=fragment";
```

I'm getting a response, no errors and after signing in and giving permissions, it redirects to my webapp with the access token as a uri parameter. i'm able to extract it from there.

However, the token i'm receiving is invalid. This is the url I get back :

```
http://localhost:8100/
#access_token=EwBgA8l6BAAUO9chh8cJscQLmU%2bLSWpbnr0vmwwAAUlVAGL4SbC2vv7LCtvlu22I81D1f/RF7ZgS/dyTW8rScVHwtOCYvhV/BinsEAymBYcZhdLbOk1eRWP250l3ExjK2lgCzg4Kib1IVkKgxUmJVU8lAvYjO1KNEPDrzVpdVArbjTTv/zxDRmsAhqQK/887jT8W0Tmg5kEwbjv/Gjlz3BOBr6XiI35cZSyJaLodYYetRUMc/PNiSm8jsy/8L0yl%2b0/P5x3BWLgAXuE7V1xFpc5/78XnTJFaOFDfG8JUpCGL08AJV1MIVz1uVfmeYVLTmU9URKqSNqX0GjUbFjKSjDIL/xV24xF2xd8sQ4XTpxrj%2bgs7rIHkDZQSe1ZcNTEDZgAACHPLh4wf/djAMAIvde8S7AhIjYALfbgwGzvfa%2bG/yqFI3ceSoiEaqFST01woiSUUf2ybVN53T6leLlzuLrmioOcSjXvhb38G04qn9zz8yfkH6deNpiomOD64YEyDJRGIrdrPwKof5bCAL8tBq/Y/0wqz2lvi5mUT7GnlgJ2zkbP%2bmsGpOzt%2bAtMU8JQDyOi3ad/nj5jriawEzmKMQmE3nFijnjGAyvoiVBUQraDuyeKJlJowcMkRWBZmcStc7paDN0npHj7Q%2bSRHRI6vYB2hJwSkIspn67rXjQ4ItvJnV7zxRpwJnmC54gcSYLdp%2b/Z6W5jXVucgvZ0IRdKHAa2HLCVFmv7q5RVdtJ2UrL5oi7vQG6fo96vpnbyLA%2bt3IGZW88Jka4AiajSRvRV4%2b19IYzp4AtzWqu9PJJxgYPwdKJjJEilSbnyDceVmndzWv/OSV4zsg6Q%2buc98PpwW47oZtgLvLvarkD%2bKwq7REadbb1yNx1XPzSO43djVtAOJLthvfvw2hXMO1koclFrMnqjVlCEU5ONEIKqwWOuiARxcpmTlqNFSVhhpzMXGCSjhE5pqWLkZqVrNpfZuKIMPW5/BT6GNITPB4vBB8r9nxJCYFzSuENS2SKjnTKQwWQcec/iJblvsXlWJPMWzwFPwV93dO0SehJEisW/ap6XefRokjwuLErYDPXwmCMP45eeZSvad21WhJi4bRKvBCBqfn8jrlKqpyLMweu/bfpR04q4B1ye5X8Z29fbq4nC6Y3oC
&token_type=bearer
&expires_in=3600
&scope=openid%20https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.Read%20https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
```

(new line characters added for readability)

the problem is that the token received is not a valid token and i'm not sure why I'm getting this.

I also tried using the GET on authorize endpoint to get the code and then using POST on token endpoint to get the token, and I get a similar response. (I disabled the web security to make the post request from my ionic app, not sure if thats relevant).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

PS I also tried using msal but I don't have routing set up, and there's way too many components so I want to avoid setting up routing if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're conflating AAD's v1 and v2 OAuth endpoints. You shouldn't be requesting a `resource` (v1) at the same time you're requesting `scope` (v2).

The correct call prototype is:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=[APPLICATION ID]
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]
&scope=[SCOPE]
&response_mode=[MODE]
```

So your actual code should look like this:

```js
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?"
    + "client_id={CLIENT_ID_HERE}"
    + "&response_type=token"
    + "&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2F"
    + "&scope=offline_access openid contacts.read contacts.read.shared user.read"
    + "&&response_mode=fragment"
```

Comment: still issues an invalid token (similar to one above) :(